# Module found but does not contain package

Tags: go, prometheus

I have a dependency issue with Go and was trying to understand the root cause, hopefully someone can shed some light.

I'm using the Prometheus go client ( https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang ) as a dependency in my Go project. This has a transitive dependency called xxhash, which is discoverable by module aware versions of Go through the virtual path of github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2. It looks like this utility was recently updated to use go modules and this is indicated by its v2 suffix.

I'm running go 1.17.7 in module mode and using the default GoPath. When I try to run go mod tidy it returns the following error.

```
github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2: module github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2@latest found (v2.1.2), but does not contain package github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2
```

I'm running in module mode and this is a transitive dependency so I expect that go will look in `$GOPATH\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\cespare\xxhash\v2\@v` to find that version. I do see that version cached in that precise folder. I also notice however that go creates a directory for the same dependency at `$GOPATH\pkg\mod\github.com\cespare\xxhash\v2@v2.1.2` but the source has not been downloaded.

I've read other threads where this was resolved by upgrading to a newer version of Go which was module aware , or alternatively upgrading the version of the Prometheus client however in this case I'm on the latest for each.

Comment: The xxhash module does not hold the v2 version in a subdirectory called `v2`, as pointed out to be recommended under "Major version strategies" on https://go.dev/blog/v2-go-modules. Are you sure environment variable `GO111MODULE` is not set to `off`?

Comment: How are you importing the package? Did you try `go clean -modcache` in case you have a corrupted local cache?

Comment: I'm importing through a private proxy mirror

Comment: Thanks, @zyl , I didn't realize it was not a physical location. When I reverted my GoPath to use proxy.golang.org the dependency did resolve. I need to understand why the private  proxy mirror is not using the correct path

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The original GOPATH configuration was using a mirror proxy, in the form of Artifactory, for dependency resolution. Checksum collisions prevented pulling in all dependencies. I reverted to proxy.golang.org to resolve the issue

Comment: "I reverted to proxy.golang.org to resolve the issue".  Can you please elaborate on this?  How precisely did you "revert" it?