# How to fork? Error: found, but does not contain package

Tags: go

Run:

```bash
go install github.com/google/gnostic@v0.6.8
go install github.com/googleapis/gnostic-grpc@v0.1.1
```

and the tool works:

```bash
gnostic --grpc-out=./target ./source.yaml
```

I've forked the library https://github.com/google/gnostic-grpc and modified it to not do any snake case conversion, and I've renamed the package and all the references to `github.com/thlib/gnostic-grpc` so that it hopefully becomes installable.

Then I tried to install it with:

```bash
go install github.com/thlib/gnostic-grpc@04d3e8500daa070fbe8c6118fe3b62e42d4a9b1f
```

and also:

```bash
go install github.com/google/gnostic@v0.6.8
go install github.com/thlib/gnostic-grpc@v0.1.3
```

But it throws the error:

```bash
go: downloading github.com/thlib/gnostic-grpc v0.1.3
go: github.com/thlib/gnostic-grpc@v0.1.3: module github.com/thlib/gnostic-grpc@v0.1.3 found, but does not contain package github.com/thlib/gnostic-grpc
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

1. package was renamed
2. ran `go mod init github.com/thlib/gnostic-grpc && go mod tidy`

Then `git clone`d the original and now I'm even more confused, how does this work at all?

```bash
go install github.com/google/gnostic@v0.6.8
go install github.com/googleapis/gnostic-grpc@v0.1.1
```

There doesn't seem to be a `main.go` package at the root level, how does `go install` know what to install?

Furthermore how does it install it at all if the package contains usage of undeclared types, e.g. `/incompatibility` has `ApiSetIncompatibility` which isn't declared anywhere, shouldn't that error?

This is in the official instructions and it errors, seems they made a mistake at some point as well:

```bash
go install github.com/google/gnostic@v0.6.8
go install github.com/google/gnostic-grpc@v0.1.1
```

I've already looked at these issues (among others and reddit posts, etc), which seem to be different:

- [go module @latest found but does not contain package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62974985/go-module-latest-found-but-does-not-contain-package)
- [Module found but does not contain package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71326945/module-found-but-does-not-contain-package)
- [go install @latest found but does not contain package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72207512/go-install-latest-found-but-does-not-contain-package)
- [go: module found but does not contain package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73435155/go-module-found-but-does-not-contain-package)
- [Golang Private Modules (v1.17) -- package found but does not contain the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870607/golang-private-modules-v1-17-package-found-but-does-not-contain-the-package)

Comment: "There doesn't seem to be a main.go package at the root level, how does go install know what to install?" main.go is a file, not a package and yes. gnostic contains a main package at the root level.

Comment: gnostic-grpc does not contain a `main.go` file at the root level on the latest `main` branch, it does contain it in the `v0.1.1` release, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Furthermore how does it install it at all if the package contains usage of undeclared types, e.g. /incompatibility has ApiSetIncompatibility which isn't declared anywhere, shouldn't that error?

**ApiSetIncompatibility** will be declared in .pb generated file after proto compile. You can find it in incompatibility/incompatibility-report.proto file on 88 line. So to resolve it you need to generate .pb files with protoc first.

Comment: Interesting, how does `go install` know to generate it automatically?

Comment: I think I got it, when the code is released it's released with the generated code! Downloading the zip contains the generated code.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen you are absolutely right. Publishing already generated .pb on github or etc. files is not the best solution because it could be too huge and might depends on consumer system

Comment: Thank you @Afv1, your insight has helped me resolve the issue, I'll post an answer along with yours on how I've resolved it, but giving you the accepted answer because I could not have done it without your help.

Answer (score 1):

The cloned code is not the same code as the released one, the released code for `v0.1.1` also contains code that was generated from protobuf files.

It did not contain the package because the compilation was failing (The go error should definitely be improved).

The solution was to download the `v0.1.1` release code for `google/gnostic-grpc`, replace what needs replacing, rename the package to the new repo (and update all of the references) and publish a new version.